# Vendor database contains table with 100 user defined string columns need to find all occurrences in that table that are not null

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a vendor database for a web application with 100 "user defined string" columns.  They have a datatype of varchar with a length of 255.

I need to return all the rows that aren't null so that I can find out what is being stored in each one.  There's no controlling for what the input has been over the years so userdefinedstring1 can contain text, dates, numbers, empty strings or NULL across multiple rows.

My initial solution was just

```
SELECT 
* 
FROM userdefinedstring table 

WHERE userdefinedstring1 IS NOT NULL 

OR userdefinedstring2 IS NOT NULL
```

repeated 98 more times.

There is likely a better way to do this but I haven't yet determined it so any tips you have are appreciated.

Comment: Do you have 1 table with 98 fields in question?  You just specify that you have a 'database' with this.

Comment: by SQL 2008 do you mean SQL Server 2008?

Comment: Yes SQL Server 2008 thanks for clairfying.

Comment: I edited the question to reflect that this is a single table in the db.  It was meant for overflow purposes and I need to figure out how it has been used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only improvement to that that I can think of would be to use `COALESCE` in the `WHERE` clause instead of `OR`:

```
SELECT *
FROM   userdefinedstringTable
WHERE  COALSECE( userdefinedstring1
               , userdefinedstring2
                ...
               ) IS NOT NULL
```

Depending on your DBMS product, there may be vendor-specific improved ways to do this, but generically, this is probably the best.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  In this case based on my limited query the  statistics show the coalesce was about 33% faster.

Answer (score 2):

RBarry's COALESCE is a good idea, and you can use this to list out all columns of interest:

```
SELECT c.name ColumnName
FROM sys.columns AS c
JOIN sys.types AS t ON c.user_type_id=t.user_type_id
WHERE t.name = 'varchar' 
   AND t.max_length = 255 
ORDER BY c.OBJECT_ID;
```

Good chance to use EXCEL to craft a query quickly:
`=A1&","` copy down to craft your badass `COALESCE` statement.

Comment: Question says 'SQL 2008' but isn't tagged, thanks for sharing standard, good to get out of my SQL Server world.

Answer (score 2):

Here is query to generate that coalesce on all columns:

```
SELECT 'SELECT *
        FROM   userdefinedstringTable
        WHERE COALESCE ('  + STUFF(
        (SELECT ', [' + name + ']'
        FROM sys.columns WHERE Object_ID = object_id('userdefinedstringTable')
        FOR XML PATH (''))
    , 1,1,'')  + ') IS NOT NULL'
```